# Which is the right location for Mockito when(...).thenReturn(...) in JUnit5? The Test itself or @BeforeClass/@BeforeEach blocks?

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, mockito, junit5, springmockito

Can anybody explain me if there is a difference between:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceMockTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @InjectMocks 
    private MyService myService = new MyServiceImpl();

    @BeforeEach
    void setMockOutput() {
        when(myRepository.get(anyString())).thenReturn("something fetched");
    }


    @Test
    void testGet() {
        assertEquals("something fetched", myService.get());
    }

}
```

and this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyServiceMockTest {

@Mock
private MyRepository myRepository;

@InjectMocks 
private MyService myService = new MyServiceImpl();

@Test
void testGet() {
when(myRepository.get()).thenReturn("something fetched");
    assertEquals("something fetched", myService.get());
}
```

}

I understand, obviously that in the first case the when(...).thenReturn() will run before every test, while in the second only will run only once. But is that the only consideration?

Also, is there a point to make it run more than once? Should I do any clean up after each method?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first example it will run *before* each test, so if instead of having only one test method you have multiple it will be execute before each of those. In your case I don't think it makes any difference.
The purpose is that if you wanted the same configuration to be the same for each test method of your class it would be easier having it in a `BeforeEach` instead of duplicating in each method.
You should do clean up only if needed, it's not something you always or never have to do, it depends from case to case.